# jQuery - missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var splitIndexArray = (unformattedArray[0]).split('=')

//alert(splitIndexArray[0]) //alerts correct value
//alert(splitIndexArray[1]) //alerts correct value

var serialNoArray[splitIndexArray[0]]=splitIndexArray[1]  //(--> this statement)
```

gives me an error saying "missing ; before statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't valid:

```
var serialNoArray[splitIndexArray[0]]
```

you want to say this:

```
var serialNoArray = [ ];
serialNoArray[splitIndexArray[0]] = splitIndexArray[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.  First, always terminate statements with a `;` -- there should be one after the `splitIndexArray` assignment.  Second, you can't combine a variable declaration and an array item assignment.  You need to somehow separate those two things for `serialNoArray`.

Comment: Semicolon terminators are usually optional in JavaScript, that doesn't mean that leaving them out is a good idea of course but you rarely *need* them.

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunately more of a guideline than a requirement. I would say it was a mistake to make semicolons optional because then you have to deal with things like this: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/